# How to completely remove porn bot in telegram group?(Only displayed in macos version)

Tags: macos

A Russian guy added an porn bot to the group.
  [image]

Then my message box has one more button.Left side of the sticker.
[image]
Even after the admin removed it, it does't disappear and only appear in this group！
[image]
I tried click stop bot and even reinstall the telegram but doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes?  This looks, to me, like a valid question.  If you down vote, please add a comment so we can understand why.

Comment: @fsb Maybe they think i should use "Ask a quesion" in telegram.I tried,the volunter support can't solve this.

Comment: Have you seen/tried this advice?  [How to Remove a Telegram Bot on PC or Mac](https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-a-Telegram-Bot-on-PC-or-Mac)